# Vapor: Can't migrate/revert from command line

Tags: ios, swift, vapor

I am trying to run migrations from the command line for a Vapor app. The basic command `swift run App` seems not to work. Here's a typical test, comparing the older syntax.

```
danieldonaldson@Daniels-Mac-mini wb2-web % vapor run  migrate      
This command is deprecated. Use `swift run App` instead.
Error: Invalid URL: /Volumes/500 GB Current/Current Work/wb2-web/Package.swift
danieldonaldson@Daniels-Mac-mini wb2-web % swift run App migrate
error: no executable product named 'App'
```

The Package.swift file is in the Active Directory and it seems to use name 'App'.

```
 targets: [
        .target(
            name: "App",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "Vapor", package: "vapor"),
                .product(name: "FluentPostgresDriver", package: "fluent-postgres-driver"),
                .product(name: "Fluent", package: "fluent"),
                .product(name: "Leaf", package: "leaf"),
//                .product(name: "SendGrid", package: "sendgrid"),
            ],
            swiftSettings: [
                // Enable better optimizations when building in Release configuration. -- Despite the use of
                // the `.unsafeFlags` construct required by SwiftPM, this flag is recommended for Release
                // builds. See <https://github.com/swift-server/guides#building-for-production> for details.
                .unsafeFlags(["-cross-module-optimization"], .when(configuration: .release))
            ]
        ),
```

although at the top, the name is different:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "Authentication",
    platforms: [
       .macOS(.v10_15)
    ],
```

but that's a name that's been in place for a couple of years, no changes have been made. I don't normally migrate or revert manually, but in this case I have to test some things. So I don't know when this cropped up, but I do need to check this...

Why would swift not find the App executable? This is pretty standard Vapor practice I believe.

Answer (score 1):

In Package.swift you have a `.target` and an `.executableTarget.` Recent Vapor 4 versions a looking at the `executableTarget` name, rather than the `target` name. Chances are that your `executableTarget` name is 'Run', so just use

```
swift run Run
```

Comment: is on to something here, however, I don't see executableTarget in the OP's config.